# JAVA - Conexão com banco - Erro SQLException: Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, sql

Olá! Sou novato em Java, e me deparei com esse problema:

O Netbeans acusa que nao estou respeitando os limites de parametro do SQL, porem estão corretos.

**Parte do erro em questão:**

```
Testando conexão com banco de dados...
jun 03, 2018 8:11:01 PM View.Autor.Autorview btnCadastrarActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of 
parameters, which is 2).
```

**Minha classe DAO com metodo que acessa o banco:**

```
public class AutorDAO {
private Connection c;

public AutorDAO(){
    this.c = new Conexao().conectar();
}

public boolean verificaAutor(Autor autor, boolean result) throws SQLException{

        PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT nome, sobrenome FROM autor "
                                                    + " WHERE nome=? AND sobrenome=?");


        stmt.setString(2, autor.getNome());
        stmt.setString(3, autor.getSobrenome());
        //RS guarda o resultado da query
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();


        if(!rs.next()){
            result=false; //Retornou null, logo nao há registros
        }
        else
            result=true; // se retorna true significa que há registro
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();

        return result;}
    public void insert(Autor autor){

    String sql="INSERT INTO autor(idAutor, nome, sobrenome) values(?,?,?);";
    try {

        stmt.setInt   (1, autor.getID());
        stmt.setString(2, autor.getNome());
        stmt.setString(3, autor.getSobrenome());

        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }      
}
}
```

**Minha classe controller que chama a DAO:**

```
public class AutorControl {

boolean result;
public void CadastraAutor(String nome, String sobrenome) throws SQLException{
   //Cria a model e DAO antes pra verificar se já existe
   Autor autor = new Autor();
   AutorDAO ad = new AutorDAO();
   //Manda o model pra verificar se ja existe
   //A result informa se já existe ou nao
   ad.verificaAutor(autor, result);
   //boolean resultado = new AutorDAO().verificaAutor();
   //Se result for false, significa que não está cadastrado
   if(result==false){
        //Não há o autor, pode cadastrar
        autor = new Autor(nome, sobrenome);
        ad.insert(autor);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Autor cadastrado com sucesso!");
   }
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Autor já cadastrado!");

    //Se retornar false significa que nao tem autor
    //Então dessa mesma classe notifica pelo JOptionPane
    //E já chama a tela de cadastro
}
}
```

EDIT1: Antes, a DAO funcionava normalmente, acessava e inseria no banco. Esse erro apareceu após algumas modificações na controller.
Se eu volto a controller como era, o programa roda e insere no banco normalmente.

**Classe controller antes do erro:**

```
public class AutorControl {

boolean result;
public void CadastraAutor(String nome, String sobrenome) throws SQLException{
   //Cria a model e DAO antes pra verificar se já existe
   Autor autor = new Autor();
   AutorDAO ad = new AutorDAO();

   autor = new Autor(nome, sobrenome);
   ad.insert(autor);

}
}
```

Comment: Substitua `stmt.setString(2, autor.getNome());` e `stmt.setString(3, autor.getSobrenome());` por `stmt.setString(1, autor.getNome());` e `stmt.setString(2, autor.getSobrenome());`, respectivamente.

Comment: cara, MUITO obrigado. Eu estava olhando essa parte achando muito suspeito, mas achava que esse index era referente a posição do atributo no banco. Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Tem como eu favoritar o comentario? Curtir, algo do tipo?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme apontado nos comentários da questão:

Substitua:

```
stmt.setString(2, autor.getNome());
stmt.setString(3, autor.getSobrenome());
```

Por:

```
stmt.setString(1, autor.getNome());
stmt.setString(2, autor.getSobrenome());
```